# Highlight or glowing border of a child node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there any way to highlight or make glowing border of a child node as following image(change appears with a graphical applications)? 
any help will be appreciated
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `circular glow` from shadows library

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,text=white,
root concept/.style={concept color=orange},
level 1 concept/.append style=
{every child/.style={concept color=orange}}]
\node [concept] {Root concept}
child[grow=30] {node[concept] {child}}
child[grow=0 ] {node[concept,circular glow={fill=orange!50}] {child}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]